# Max persistent connection settings in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox

How do I change the Max persistent connection for Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Type `about:config` in the address bar. Click "OK, I promise".

Type `network.http.max-persistent` in the opened search bar. You'll see two settings below:

```
network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-proxy; 8
network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server; 6
```

Change them as you want.